# Binding View Data on Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the current ViewModel:

```
public class ServiceSheetViewModel
{
    public List<ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel> questions { get; set; }
    public List<VehicleAction> actions { get; set; }
}
```

And, on the view, I'm generating the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.questions[j], "ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel");
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model.actions[i], "VehicleAction");
```

On the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateServiceSheet([Bind(Include = "questions,actions")]  ServiceSheetViewModel model, int vehicleId, int serviceSheetId)
```

When I submit the form, it is not binding.

On the post information, its saying its sending a List of `ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel` and a List of `VehicleActions`.

How is the proper way to make the form bind correctly?

EDIT 1 - View Code

```
@model  SupervisedSolutions.Models.ViewModels.ServiceSheetViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateServiceSheet", "PerformService", Model))
{
    ....
    @foreach (var rootItem in Model.questions.Where(x => x.Question.IsGroup || (!x.Question.IsGroup && (x.Question.ParentQuestion == null || x.Question.ParentQuestion.ID == 0))).ToList())
    {
        var i = Model.questions.IndexOf(rootItem);
        if (Model.questions[i].Question.IsGroup)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.Title)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.Description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.IsGroup)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.OrderIndex)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.ParentQuestion.ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.ParentQuestion.setDeleted)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.ParentQuestion.Title)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.questions[i].Question.ParentQuestion.Created)
            <h1>@Model.questions[i].Question.Title</h1>
            <p>@Model.questions[i].Question.Description</p>
            ....
            @foreach (var item in Model.questions.Where(x => !x.Question.IsGroup && (x.Question.ParentQuestion != null && x.Question.ParentQuestion.ID == Model.questions[i].Question.ID)).ToList())
            {
                var j = Model.questions.IndexOf(item);
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.questions[j], "ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.questions[i], "ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel");
        }
    }
    @foreach (var todo in Model.actions)
    {
        var i = Model.actions.IndexOf(todo);
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.actions[i], "VehicleAction");
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Start Run" class="btn btn-info" />
}
```

This is the `EditorTemplate` for `ServiceSheetQuestionsViewModel`:

```
@model SupervisedSolutions.Models.ViewModels.ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel
....
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.Title)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.Description)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.IsGroup)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.OrderIndex)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.ParentQuestion.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.ParentQuestion.setDeleted)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.ParentQuestion.Title)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question.ParentQuestion.Created)
<b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Question.Title)</b>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isFault, "Fault")Fault
</label>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isFault, "NoFault")No Fault
</label>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FaultDescription)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FaultDescription)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FaultDescription)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.isFault)
```

And this is the `EditorTemplate` for `Vehicle Action`:

```
@model SupervisedSolutions.Models.VehicleAction

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Priority)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.DueDate>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueDate)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DueDate)
```

EDIT 2 - Here is the information on the post data:

```
vehicleId:50
serviceSheetId:1
ID:0
questions[1].Question.ID:3
questions[1].Question.Title:Testing
questions[1].Question.Description:AASDASD
questions[1].Question.IsGroup:True
questions[1].Question.OrderIndex:1
questions[1].Question.ParentQuestion.ID:
questions[1].Question.ParentQuestion.setDeleted:
questions[1].Question.ParentQuestion.Title:
questions[1].Question.ParentQuestion.Created:
questions[0].Question.ID:1
questions[0].Question.Title:Test Question
questions[0].Question.Description:Habba
questions[0].Question.IsGroup:False
questions[0].Question.OrderIndex:0
questions[0].Question.ParentQuestion.ID:3
questions[0].Question.ParentQuestion.setDeleted:False
questions[0].Question.ParentQuestion.Title:Testing
questions[0].Question.ParentQuestion.Created:28/11/2016 7:35:12 PM
questions[0].isFault:NoFault
questions[0].FaultDescription:Teste
questions[3].Question.ID:5
questions[3].Question.Title:Group 2
questions[3].Question.Description:Groupin 2
questions[3].Question.IsGroup:True
questions[3].Question.OrderIndex:0
questions[3].Question.ParentQuestion.ID:
questions[3].Question.ParentQuestion.setDeleted:
questions[3].Question.ParentQuestion.Title:
questions[3].Question.ParentQuestion.Created:
questions[2].Question.ID:4
questions[2].Question.Title:Test Question 23
questions[2].Question.Description:TEEEE
questions[2].Question.IsGroup:False
questions[2].Question.OrderIndex:0
questions[2].Question.ParentQuestion.ID:5
questions[2].Question.ParentQuestion.setDeleted:False
questions[2].Question.ParentQuestion.Title:Group 2
questions[2].Question.ParentQuestion.Created:1/12/2016 4:19:49 PM
questions[2].isFault:NoFault
questions[2].FaultDescription:Teste
actions[0].Description:Erro2
actions[0].Priority:1
actions[0].DueDate:2010-01-01
```

Comment: Show you view (the loop you generating the form controls in and the EditorTemplates your using for `ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel` and `VehicleAction`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the full HTML for the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove your `[Bind]` attribute (that attribute is not required when using view models).

To start with the easy one, replace the `@foreach (var todo in Model.actions){ ... }` loop for `actions` with just

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.actions)
```

and ensure your `EditorTemplate` is located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `/Views/youControllerName/EditorTemplates`) folder, and is named `VehicleAction.cshtml`. The `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and will correctly generate the html for each item in the collection.

The issue with `questions` not binding is that the `DefaultModelBinder` (by default) requires that collection indexers start at zero and be consecutive. Your logic in the `@foreach (var rootItem in Model.questions.Where.....` and `@foreach (var item in Model.questions.Where...` and in particular the `if (Model.questions[i].Question.IsGroup){ ... } else { ... }` block means that you are not generating consecutive indexers (your request shows that they are in order `[1]`, `[0]`, `[3]`, `[2]`).

One way to solve this is to include a hidden input for the collection indexer to override the default behavior of the `DefaultModelBinder`, but that means you cannot use an `EditorTemplate` and you will need `for` loops to generate the controls. Refer the first code snippet in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) for an example of the necessary hidden input.

However, that kind of logic does not belong in a view, especially since you already using view models. Your `ServiceSheetViewModel` should have 2 collection properties for `ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel`, say

```
public List<ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel> GroupedQuestions { get; set; }
public List<ServiceSheetQuestionViewModel> UngroupedQuestions { get; set; }
```

and you populate those collections in the controller based on the value of `IsGroup`. Then in the view you can simply use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.GroupedQuestions)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UngroupedQuestions)
```

to handle the `if/else` block that your currently using in the view.

You have not provided enough information to understand what the logic in `foreach` loops are doing, but it appears you have a hierarchical structure based on your `ParentQuestion` properties, which means that your view models should also have a hierarchical structure, i.e. a `Question` needs to contains a `List<Question> SubQuestions` property so that you can use `nested` `EditorTemplates` or `for` loops.

As a side note, rendering all those hidden inputs is unnecessary and bad practice (a malicious user can easily post back bad data and you just degrading performance). Just generate a hidden input for the questions `ID` property and when you submit, get the original from the database based on the ID and update only those properties you edit in the view based on the view model.